# How to set variable for use in other function?

Tags: java, android, variables

Why I set Icao = WSSS but OnclickListener call Icao = null don't use = WSSS.

Guide to me please.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String ans[] ={"","",""};
    String Icao ="";
    String url = String.format("http://flightxml.flightaware.com/json/FlightXML2/Search?query=-destination%%20%s",Icao);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Icao = "WSSS";   // <<< don't use this value 

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            getInput(url);  
            txt1.setText(ans[0]);

        } });
        }
```

Comment: what do u want to do?? write in detail

Comment: Check the answer and give some feedback.

Comment: @AnilBhatiya I'm clear this question.Sorry for question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make global variable

```
String url;
```

now on onCreate() method after set

```
Icao = "WSSS";  

url = String.format("http://flightxml.flightaware.com/json/FlightXML2/Search?query=-destination%%20%s",Icao);
```

***Your Full Code.***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String ans[] ={"","",""};
String Icao ="";
String url ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Icao = "WSSS";   
   url = String.format("http://flightxml.flightaware.com/json/FlightXML2/Search?query=-destination%%20%s",Icao);

  btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        getInput(url);  
        txt1.setText(ans[0]);

    } });
    }
```

Where in your code your

***Icao*** string is null and you have passed to url initially.So obviously you get null always. So change as per my answer.

Comment: @user3305512 ur wel come...glad 2 help you!!